# "Conta do Google: tentativa de login bloqueada" - App Android

Tags: java, android

Dê uma olhada primeiro no meu código

classe LoginActivity

```
package com.softblue.sendemail;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnSubmit;
    EditText TxtPara, TxtTitulo, Txtmsg;

    Session session = null;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
    Context context = null;

    String rec, subject, textMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        context = this;
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        TxtPara = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_para);
        TxtTitulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_titulo);
        Txtmsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_corpo);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rec = TxtPara.getText().toString();
        subject = TxtTitulo.getText().toString();
        textMessage = Txtmsg.getText().toString();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("email_de_origem@gmail.com",// aqui é para colocar o seu email
                        "senha");//aqui é para colocar a senha do seu email
            }

        });

        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, " ", "enviado o email", true);
        RetrieveFeedTask task = new RetrieveFeedTask();
        task.execute();

    }

    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(
                        "email_de_origem@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(rec));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(message);

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pdialog.dismiss();
            TxtPara.setText("");
            TxtTitulo.setText("");
            Txtmsg.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "mensagem enviada com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

}
```

login_activity.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_para"
        android:hint="Enviar Para"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_titulo"
        android:hint="Itulo do Email"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_corpo"
        android:hint="Corpo do Email"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="enviar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_enviar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.softblue.sendemail"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Na verdade estou seguindo esse tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNPFWCNMJPU

Quando executei pela primeira vez, achei que tinha dado certo porque eu recebi esse email:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao tentar executar pela segunda vez, não funcionou.
Eu mandei a aplicação para um amigo meu, ele me falou que testou no celular dele e funcionou.

Eu acredito que seja configuração da minha conta de Gmail ou pode ser alguma informação faltando no meu algorítimo do LoginActivity.

Aceito sugestões.

As configurações da porta SMTP da google foram daqui:

http://www.serversmtp.com/pt-pt/servidor-smtp-gmail-configuracao

eu tentei tanto ativada como desativada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vai la onde diz "Se foi você" no link e libera o login para aplicações menos seguras

Comment: dá uma olhada na minha postagem, eu tentei da duas maneiras e  não funcionou.

Comment: Não fiz com app ainda, porém já trabalhei com JavaMail, e tive o mesmo problema, pra mim bastou eu permitir o acesso como na imagem acima que funcionou, outra coisa verifica seu anti virus @wladyband

Answer (score 1):

Eu precisei fazer, mas essa resposta funcionou para +400 pessoas...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124